# Division between two safe integers resulting in TypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

With Javascript ES5, dividing `0` with a safe integer: `8007199254740991` is giving me the following TypeError:

> TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number

Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
console.log('Numerator is ' + row.num);
console.log('Denominator is ' + row.den);
console.log('Result is' + row.num ? row.num / row.den : 123);
```

The output is:

```
Numerator is 0 
Denominator is 8007199254740991
TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number
```

Both row.num and row.den are of es5 type number. Could someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: "are of es5 type number" how do you know?

Comment: @JonasWilms Going to source for the number type led me to lib.es5.d.ts. Is there a better way to verify?

Comment: Well, then someone misstyped that BigInt as number.

Comment: If you write `console.log(typeof row.num)` and `console.log(typeof row.den)` I think you'll find that one of them is `bigint` and not `number`. Where are you actually setting those properties?  Are you doing it in TypeScript or JavaScript?  If TypeScript, is the assignment strongly typed or are you using something like type assertions?  I think we need more info for this to be a [mcve]

Comment: @jcalz You're right. It looks like the type of the denominator is shown as bigint. This is typescript and my example is based on this : https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/web-console/src/views/services-view/services-view.tsx#L436
Even though max_size(row.den here) is defined as a number here: https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/web-console/src/views/services-view/services-view.tsx#L120
is it possible that it gets implicitly cast to Bigint?

Comment: "implicitly cast to Bigint" doesn't really happen in JavaScript or TypeScript.  It's probably fairly explicit, wherever it's happening.  But without a [mcve] I can actually test, this is just speculation.  I suggest that you either produce code that demonstrates your issue to others (such as with a link to a properly configure web IDE project or a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?)), or start working on providing enough information that someone can help you debug this remotely... but the reproducible example is likely to be more fruitful.